# C# - How to find most frequent date from list

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I seem to have drawn a blank. I have a list of sales, retrieved like so:

```
List<Sales> sales = ctn.Sales.Where(s => s.DateSold >= request.FromDate && s.DateSold <= request.ToDate).ToList();
```

An item in the list of sales would look something like the following:

> SaleID | DateSold | ProductID | ShopID

As part of a report, I would like to return to the user a simple string informing them of what day is the day that tends to sell the most.

So I think what I should do is group sales by day, get a count for each day, and then evaluate which has the highest number, however I'm not sure exactly how to do this.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just have to group on the `DateSold` and then order by the count (which tells you how many items belong to the group):

```
salesByDay = sales.GroupBy(s => s.DateSold).OrderBy(g => g.Count());
```

Comment: Understand that if DateSold include timestamp information, they'll be near-unique. You can remove the timestamp for the purposes of grouping by grouping on the Date property of the DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the exact DateTime of sold item into DateSold, you probably want to take Date part and group by it

```
from sale in sales
group sale by sale.DateSold.Date into grouped
orderby grouped.Count()
select new {Date = grouped.Key, Count = grouped.Count()};
```

Answer (score 0):

This will provide you the date with the most sales:

`sales.GroupBy(x => x.DateSold).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()).FirstOrDefault().Key;`